# PHP "echo" not working before curl function

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, php-curl

```
  funtion request(){

  echo "Success";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_error = curl_errno($ch);
  $getserver = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

here success echo only shows after exicuting curl function . i wanna 
echo the success message before curl function calls.

Comment: Where did  u call the function?

Comment: If you are running this in a browser, it will only (normally) return the contents once the page has finished running.

Comment: codeigniter controller

Comment: This can also happen because the output is buffered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is in the controller and you are calling from a different function in the same file, you need to call `$this->request()`, let me convey this information.

Later,

maybe you can return a result with `return "Success";`